# Get JSONArray with StringRequest from Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to get hold of a JSONArray by using StringRequest in Android along with the POST-method.

The php-script is written like:

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE user_id > 5 AND completed = 1");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "i", $UID);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $beacon_id, $timeFrom, $timeTo, $completed);



    $jsonObject = array();
    $response = array();

    while($status = mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
            $jsonObject = null;

            $jsonObject["beacon_id"]= $beacon_id;
            $jsonObject["timeFrom"]= $timeFrom;
            $jsonObject["timeTo"]= $timeTo;

            $response[] = $jsonObject;
    }

echo json_encode($response);?>
```

Accessing the web-page with the php-script, the following JSONArray is "echoed":

```
[{"beacon_id":10,"timeFrom":"2018-02-14 13:07:11","timeTo":"2018-02-14 14:32:53"},{"beacon_id":3,"timeFrom":"2018-02-24 13:33:37","timeTo":"2018-02-24 13:33:47"}]
```

And as I understand this is a normal JSONArray with square-brackets representing the array and curly-brackets for each JSONObject inside the array.

When I try to access this JSONArray through a StringRequest in Android Studio (Java), I do not get any results...

The StringRequest code:

```
public class HistoryRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String HISTORY_REQUEST_URL = "http://myURL.../myPHPfile.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public HistoryRequest(String user_id, String instanceID, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, HISTORY_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("user_id", user_id);
        params.put("instanceID", instanceID);
}

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {return params;}
}
```

The ResponseListener in the MainActivity is written like:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String timeFrom = jsonObject.getString("timeFrom");
        String timeTo = jsonObject.getString("timeTo");

        textviewFrom.append(timeFrom);
        textviewTo.append(timeTo);
        }
    }
};
```

Any tips why I can't make a JSONArray of the String that in the web-page URL looks like a beautiful JSONArray?

Thanks in advance!

### **UPDATE:**

After switching to JSONArrayRequest instead of StringRequest, I can get the data if I change the MySQL part of the php-script to something static like:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets;
```

Then I can display all the entries. But I tend to send 1 parameter to the server (user_id), so that I can filter the entries based on the user that is logged in. [SELECT * FROM tickets where user_id = ?], like a traditional POST-method....

Someone who knows what to do? Read several places that you can not @Override the getParams()-method for this...

### **SOLVED:**

I solved the issue by entering the keyvalue (user_id) into the URL.

```
//Instead of POST:
$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];

// I use SERVER to get the value after ? in the URL:
$user_id = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Doing this with the following java-code:

```
public class HistoryRequest extends JsonArrayRequest {
private static final String HISTORY_REQUEST_URL = "http://myURLorIPaddress/getHistory.php?";

    public HistoryRequest(String UID, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener) throws JSONException {
        super(Method.POST, HISTORY_REQUEST_URL + UID,null, listener, null);
}
}
```

This made it possible to filter the result based on user_id and works like a charm :D

Comment: Can you try to print the string response that you are getting and verify?

Comment: Please look at the answer below :)

Comment: Do not supply the additional material as an answer to the question. Use `Edit` button to edit your question and add additional info. It seems that your request is throwing an error and is not even hitting an API. You can look at the response once you figure out what's wrong with the request.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get to print anything, but I can see that the Volley library is complaining for some external errors (nothing referred to my code). The log.i("OnResponseLog", response) does not provide anything.

[Picture of error from LogCat:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nHJq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am working in similar project did you check if there are some null entries? I think the problem might be there by checking your LogCat picture.

Check using isNull() function might be good idea.
https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject_isNull_.html